# On an integral of Gaussian CDFs

Tags: probability-distributions, integration

Let $c>0$ and $T>0$ be fixed. Denote by $F$ the Gaussian CDF, i.e. $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is defined by

$$F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}dz.$$

For every $a\in [0,1)$, does there exist $C\equiv C_a>0$ s.t.

$$\left|\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s-t}\left(F\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{c(s-t)}}\right)-F\left(\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{c(s-t)}}\right)\right) dy\right| \le \frac{C|x|^a}{(s-t)^{(1+a)/2}}$$

holds for all $0\le t<s\le T$ and $x\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: Just to clarify, may $C$ depend on $T$ and $c$ as well?

Comment: Yes, $C$ must depend on $c$. In this question, $C$ can also depend on $T$ (while I believe $C$ does not depend on $T$ but I didn't get it by calculus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Indeed, let
$$u:=\frac x{\sqrt{c(s-t)}}.$$
Then, with the substitution $z:=\dfrac y{\sqrt{c(s-t)}}$, the inequality in question can be rewritten as
$$|I(u)|\le C|u|^a \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for all real $u$, where
$$I(u):=\int_0^\infty dz\,(F(z)-F(z-u)).$$

For $u>0$,
$$I(u)=\int_0^\infty dz\,\int_{z-u}^z dF(t)
=\int_{-u}^\infty dF(t)\int_0^\infty dz\,1(t<z<t+u) \\ 
\ge\int_0^\infty dF(t)\,u=\frac12\,u. $$
Similarly, $|I(u)|\le|\int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\,(F(z)-F(z-u))|=|u|$ for all real $u$.

So,
\eqref{1} holds for all real $u$ if and only if $a=1$.
(This conclusion actually holds for any cdf $F$ such that $F(0-)<1$.)

Comment: Nice arguments. Many thanks Iosif!

Comment: You are very welcome!